# How can I set an output of files to a directory on the server for a remote git bare repository?

Tags: git

I have installed git on the server. There are already plenty of files in the project directory (www/beta/httpdocs). I want to setup a remote bare repository where I and a few people could push to.

We want to connect that repo to a directory in the wwwroot so that when someone pushes their files to the repo, the files are automatically copied to the wwwroot of our beta domain (beta.server.com) where we could test for bugs.  When we are satisfied with the quality, I would copy the files to the main domain (which is on the same server, just in another directory) manually, or if I find another more profound way.

It's very important that I somehow add these already existing files on the server to the bare repo.

Comment: take a look at [jenkins-ci](http://jenkins-ci.org/)

Comment: Sorry, but i really need a solution with the existing software. Perhaps git hooks or something like that? The server is CentOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, to add the current files, `git init` then setup a remote branch to push to.  Then on your server setup a post-receive hook that runs a deploy off to your service, basically triggering a `git pull`

Comment: So while logged onto our server via ssh, i should go to wwwroot and do git init, then create a project.git folder that would contain the bare repository somewhere. But how do i push the files from wwwroot, that would then contain .git, to the bare repo located localy? All the project files are on the server so my first commit has to be from there.

Comment: `git remote add NAME file:///path/to/gitrepo`
OR
`git remote add NAME USER@HOST:/path/to/gitrepo`
then just git pull/push

Comment: How do i set up post-receive hooks to deploy everything into a directory from that bare repo?

Comment: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks - basically its just a script - so put something like this in it: `#!/bin/sh cd $WWWDIR; git pull; exit 0`

Comment: thanks, I got it working now. I had to add unset GIT_DIR, to your code to make it work.